flutter project failed to run after upgrading to the latest android studio IDE called Ladybug. I experience error with pusher client package
The error occur only with pusher package. I have tried several pusher package but they all seem to have this common error in the my project.
Below is my app/build.gradle file.
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.cartrackernigeria.ctntelematics"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.cartrackernigeria.ctntelematics"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = 21//flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}


Below is setting.gradle file
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
//    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}

include ":app"


Below is my android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


I get this error below each time when I try to run the flutter project.
I have tried everything that I could but I do not understand, while pusher is complaining about namespace. I have tried several pusher package version such as

pusher_client
pusher_client_fixed
pusher_client_x


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':pusher_client_x'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

     If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Error executing devicectl: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 3:

User cancelled

ERROR: Error writing JSON results: The file “core_device_list.json” doesn’t exist. (NSCocoaErrorDomain error 4.)
         NSFilePath = /var/folders/9p/qyg46tks79g_66b7y5bk3f800000gn/T/flutter_tools.Hff1N6/core_devices.dnTZUa/core_device_list.json
       ----------------------------------------
       The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory (NSPOSIXErrorDomain error 2.)
  Command: xcrun devicectl list devices --timeout 5 --json-output /var/folders/9p/qyg46tks79g_66b7y5bk3f800000gn/T/flutter_tools.Hff1N6/core_devices.dnTZUa/core_device_list.json


In ladybug when creating new flutter project it's not running. shows error:
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

If you are using Android Studio Ladybug, you need at least AGP version 8.7
To use this version, you must make at least two changes in your project.
Update the setting.gradle file to set the com.android.application plugin to
id "com.android.application" version "8.7.0" apply false

and check your gradle-wrapper.properties file. Here, you must set the distributionUrl to the minimum required Gradle version. For AGP version 8.7, this is at least Gradle 8.10
An example of the updated distributionUrl could be:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip

All in all for similar problems in the future just check the Android Gradle plugin release notes
